# How to check for matching in SQLite in order to insert new data or update them?

Tags: sqlite, sql-update, sql-insert, unique-constraint, upsert

I want to insert data into a table if no matching value for column EqpCode exists. If there were any matches, I want to update that row.
I used this query but it has syntax error near WHERE:

```
INSERT INTO FileInfo(EqpCode, EqpName, FileName) VALUES ('123', 'test01', 'test02') 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM FileInfo WHERE EqpCode='123')
```

Comment: Is EqpCode the PRIMARY KEY or is it defined as UNIQUE?

Comment: No, I defined them as VARCHAR

Comment: Don't you want EqpCode to be UNIQUE?

Comment: Yeah, I want to make it UNIQUE.

Comment: Which SQL type should I use? UNIQUEIDENTIFIER?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you must define the column `EqpCode` to be `UNIQUE` (or the `PRIMARY KEY` if there isn't one in the table):

```
CREATE TABLE FileInfo(
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  EqpCode TEXT UNIQUE, 
  EqpName TEXT, 
  FileName TEXT
);
```

Then use SQLite's [`UPSERT`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_upsert.html):

```
INSERT INTO FileInfo(EqpCode, EqpName, FileName) VALUES ('123', 'test01', 'test02')
ON CONFLICT(EqpCode) DO UPDATE 
SET EqpName = EXCLUDED.EqpName,
    FileName = EXCLUDED.FileName;
```

This way, the new row will be inserted only if `'123'` does not exist in the table.
If it does exist, the row will be updated with the provided values of `EqpName`  and `FileName`.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=56cd726dfb077920fe0e1be6072b3821).

Comment: Thanks. It works. I learned something new.